# How to run a simple npm command as a cron job in elastic beanstalk environment?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, cron, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Node.js application running on aws elasticbeanstalk. I want to periodically run the 'npm update' command in the root of the application. I use .config files in .ebextensions folder to do other tasks such as sending logs to papertrail. So I researched a bit to find something similar for cron jobs and found this article https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cron-job-elastic-beanstalk/

But looks like this is meant for worker environments only. I just need to run 'npm update' on my application daily so that it updates the npm packages without having to re-deploy/re-build the environment. What's the easy way to add this specific cronjob to my EBS app?

Comment: I'm not sure updating in this way is really the best idea. Ideally you'd have some simple CI/CD pipeline that would rebuild, update, test, then deploy/replace.

Comment: @jarmod ideally that's what we would want to do but the thing is that rebuilding the environment takes a 7-8 minutes downtime which is not desirable. I am trying to do this update just to make sure that we don't need to rebuild for just an npm package update.

Comment: The blue/green deployment option in EB claims zero downtime for your app. Have you looked at that option?

Comment: @jarmod the thing is that we have our mongo models on an npm package. Whenever we update that package, we need all EBS applications to run npm update and get the latest models package. We don't need to deploy new code to those applications since we might not have new code.